# Rails: Separating ApplicationController from ApiController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My `app/` folder looks like this

```
.
├── controllers
|   └── api
|       └── v1
|           ├── card_controller.rb
|           └── user_controller.rb
|   └── website
|       └── account_controller.rb
...
```

I'd like the controllers in the `website` folder to inherit from a `WebsiteController` and the controllers in the `api` folder to inherit from an `ApiController`. How can this be achieved? Specifically, what files need to be created, and what class definitions must be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating inheritable classes in `controllers/website/website_controller.rb` and `controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb`.

You may use the following to easily inherit from these new controllers. This is similar to how the default generated Rails app has every controller inherit from `ApplicationController`.

### Files

#### website_controller.rb

```
class WebsiteController < ApplicationController
end
```

#### account_controller.rb

```
class AccountController < WebsiteController
end
```

### Alternatives

- It might be possible to metaprogram inheritance or includes for files in these directories, though I recommend against it to make your code more readable.
- If your inheritable classes just solve one specific problem each, or have miscellaneous helper functions and not much else, you should probably use concerns or helpers respectively instead.
- If you only need this level for inheritance for your API and the rest of your app, it might be best to extract your API into a separate application (which may or may not be a Rails app).